# C# deserialize recursive interfaces set a property dynamically

Tags: c#, json.net

what I want to do is be able to deserialize any IBaseModel and it will recursively set all IBaseModel to either Safe or Unsafe depending on what is making the call. I am currently using Newtonsoft but would be happy to switch to System.Text.Json if it will achieve the desired results.

I have the following structure:

```
public enum RequestPermissionType
    {
        Safe = 1,
        Unsafe = 2,
    }

public interface IBaseModel {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public RequestPermissionType PermissionType { get; set; }

}
public class User : IBaseModel {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public RequestPermissionType PermissionType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address HomeAddress { get; set; }
}
public class Address: IBaseModel {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public RequestPermissionType PermissionType { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
}
```

I tried creating a JsonConverter but I still want deserialize everything normally I just want to set either so when I override ReadJson i think it keeps calling deserialize using the same converter:

```
public override IBaseEntity ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, [AllowNull] IBaseEntity existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var result =  serializer.Deserialize<IBaseEntity >(reader);
            result.PermissionType = _requestPermissionType;
            return result;
        }
```

I also tried using a converter that extended CustomCreationConverter, which works but I am trying to avoid using the activator:

```
public class PermissionTypeConverter : CustomCreationConverter<IBaseEntity>
    {
        private RequestPermissionType _requestPermissionType = RequestPermissionType.Unsafe;
        
        public PermissionTypeConverter()
        {
            _requestPermissionType = RequestPermissionType.Unsafe;
        }
        public PermissionTypeConverter(RequestPermissionType requestPermissionType)
        {
            _requestPermissionType = requestPermissionType;
        }

        public override IBaseEntity Create(Type objectType)
        {
            var result = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
            (result as IBaseEntity).PermissionType = _requestPermissionType;
            return result as IBaseEntity;
        }
    }
```

Edit: Adding Json data example.

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "User 1",
      "homeAddress": {
        "id": 5,
        "street": "Fake Street 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "User 2",
      "homeAddress": {
        "id": 6,
        "street": "Fake Street 2"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Can you also give a sample json for this?

Comment: @tontonsevilla I have updated the question to add some json data. This would deserialize correctly using: JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<User>>(data). But I would like to have the ability to set PermissionType on both users and both Addresses (in my real world usecase there could be 100 nested objects) to either Safe or Unsafe, programatically, so I can choose when I set them to which value.

Comment: So do you want the `Address.PermissionType` property to be set to the same value as `User.PermissionType` when deserialising the user? or do you want everything that is being deserialised to be set to a specific PermissionType?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using `Activator`?